# Are connections in the human brain directed?

Tags: neuroscience

Do connections in our brain have a direction, or do they behave equally in both directions? I am especially interested in the structures responsible for memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two kinds of neuron-to-neuron connections in the brain.  The most well known is the chemical synapse, which is unidirectional.  Despite this, two neurons can each synapse on each other with a chemical synapse, and both types of connection are observable in brain networks (unidirectional and bidirectional)

The second kind of connection is a gap-junction: electrical coupling.  In this case, it can be bidirectional or unidirectional, but all in the same synapse (whereas a bidirectional chemical synapse requires two synapses).

Typically, the chemical synapses are associated with memory.  There have been synapses observed that behave as [engrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engram_%28neuropsychology%29).

Comment: Also bidirectional chemical connections are more common than would be expected from a random network http://www.plosbiology.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pbio.0030068